# PDO - select data from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I want to take all the data from two tables with the same user_id, but I don't know what type of join to use and I want to be sure with the syntax of the query.

"users" table:
[image]

"schedule" table:

[image]

Comment: A SQL query goes into a bar, walks up to two tables and asks, "Can I join you?" -[Adam Neal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)

Comment: @Your Common Sense I appreciate the edit but I specified clearly that I want to be sure with the syntax.

Comment: And what's wrong with the edit?

Comment: sorry my fault, i didnt specify that ill be using it on a php code, your link is for pure sql syntax.

Comment: Joins are SQL thing so I have no idea what PHP code you are talking about

Comment: yah but some syntax there are not the same when you incorporate it to a php function. it might have some slight difference that's why i want it to be specific.

Comment: If you have no idea how to run an SQL query in PHP that's another question and it should be asked separately. Ask one question at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple LEFT JOIN example:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `schedule` ON `users`.`userid` = `schedule`.`user_id` 
WHERE `users`.`userid` = ?
```

this will collect everything from both tables and then you can output it accordingly.